# Unusual ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error

Tags: java, arraylist, error-handling, indexoutofboundsexception

I keep getting an error every time I run the following method. Even though the list isn't empty error still persists.

```
public Position getBestMove() {
    int max = -10000;
    int best = -1;
    System.out.println("CALLED");
    System.out.println(successorEvaluations.size());
    // iterate over successors and return the one with the highest eval result
    for (int i = 0; i < successorEvaluations.size(); i++) { 
        if (max < successorEvaluations.get(i).score) {
            max = successorEvaluations.get(i).score;
            best = i;
        }
    }
    return successorEvaluations.get(best).pos;
}
```

error output:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at Board.getBestMove(Board.java:151)
```

Comment: Is your application running in multiple threads and could successorEvaluations be altered from the other Thread? I don't see anything in your code that should result in an ArrayOutOfBoundsException if there is only one thread.

Comment: Are you sure that initializing `max` to `-10000` is correct? What range of values do you expect `successorEvaluations.get(i).score` to hold?

Comment: What are the contents of this array against which you're testing?

Answer (score 1):

`best` is -1, which is an illegal array index. The `if` condition was not fulfilled.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously your variable 'best'  was not set after initialization.. it means that expression
if (max < successorEvaluations.get(i).score)
gave every time 'false'..
or maybe your ArrayList was empty.

Answer (score 0):

in case best value is not altered in your logic (in for loop), its value will remain unchanged, i.e. -1. And -1 is an illegal index. Thats why this exception.
Try changing the input data in your arraylist and put conditional statement for error handling. like

```
if(best == -1){
 return null;// or some default Position as per your requirements
}
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI with java 8 you can write this much simpler

```
public Position getBestMove() {
   return successorEvaluations.stream().max(s -> s.score()).get().pos();
}
```

You could consider handling an empty successorEvaluations, like this since the get() will throw a NullpointerException if list is empty:

```
public Position getBestMove() {
   return successorEvaluations.stream()
                              .max(s -> s.score())
                              .orElseThrow(new BestMoveNotFoundException())
                              .pos();
}
```

or return a default value

```
public Position getBestMove() {
   return successorEvaluations.stream()
                              .max(s -> s.score())
                              .orElse(DEFAULT_SUCCESSOR_EVALUATION)
                              .pos();
}
```